# Suppress scientific Number and fixed it to float64

Tags: python, oracle

I have a forecasting model that uses Arima, UCM and Prophet stats techniques and provides the best choice of these 3 using the prediction accuracy. all is fine but Problem is when i push these result to Oracle table i get "value cannot be represented as oracle number" error.
I believe the issue is due to the scientific notation values generated by the forecasting model
An sample output below generated by the models. how can i convert these columns to float64 which is also the data type of the oracle table for these columns

```
hierarchy_id     date                 yhat      predicted_arima predicted_ucm   arima_error ucm_error   prophet_error lowesterror   value
Corporate RE    2022-03-01 00:00:00 -0.411459092    9.1503E-140 -0.589134852    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   9.1503E-140
Corporate RE    2022-07-01 00:00:00 -0.906894815    1.9944E-140 -0.784170781    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   1.9944E-140
Corporate RE    2022-11-01 00:00:00 -0.982113949    2.7108E-141 -0.980360655    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   2.7108E-141
Corporate RE    2022-12-01 00:00:00 -0.90968317     1.0744E-141 -1.029453484    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   1.0744E-141
Corporate RE    2023-03-01 00:00:00 -0.832041608    2.0119E-142 -1.176736212    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   2.0119E-142
Corporate RE    2023-04-01 00:00:00 -1.067417334    3.5068E-142 -1.225830381    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   3.5068E-142
Corporate RE    2023-08-01 00:00:00 0.159184007     6.6025E-143 -1.422206649    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   6.6025E-143
Corporate RE    2023-12-01 00:00:00 -1.320605646    9.3166E-144 -1.618582815    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   9.3166E-144
Corporate RE    2024-01-01 00:00:00 -1.368091114    3.1386E-144 -1.667676857    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   3.1386E-144
Corporate RE    2024-04-01 00:00:00 -1.383545725    9.3886E-145 -1.814958981    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   9.3886E-145
Corporate RE    2024-05-01 00:00:00 -1.533645007    9.0269E-145 -1.864053023    3.286E-118  0.473214851 0.932848097   ARIMA error   9.0269E-145
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: a minimal `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the a minimal example of the python code that is inserting the data and generating the error; and the full text of the error.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, the value 1e-140 cannot be represented as a [`NUMBER` data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6) (and a `FLOAT` is just a sub-type of `NUMBER`):

> | Code | Data Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | `NUMBER [ (p [, s]) ]` | Number having precision `p` and scale `s`. The precision `p` can range from 1 to 38. The scale `s` can range from -84 to 127. Both precision and scale are in decimal digits. A `NUMBER` value requires from 1 to 22 bytes. |
> | 2 | `FLOAT [(p)]` | A subtype of the `NUMBER` data type having precision `p`. A FLOAT value is represented internally as `NUMBER`. The precision `p` can range from 1 to 126 binary digits. A `FLOAT` value requires from 1 to 22 bytes. |
> | 101 | `BINARY_DOUBLE` | 64-bit floating point number. This data type requires 8 bytes. |

As the maximum scale is 127 which could store values down to `1e-127`. Your values go down to `1e-140` which is too small and would be rounded to `0`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (predicted_arima NUMBER);
INSERT INTO table_name (predicted_arima) VALUES ( 9.1503E-140 );
INSERT INTO table_name (predicted_arima) VALUES ( 1E-127 );
SELECT predicted_arima, DUMP(predicted_arima) FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | PREDICTED_ARIMA | DUMP(PREDICTED_ARIMA) |
> | --- | --- |
> | 0 | Typ=2 Len=1: 128 |
> | .0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 | Typ=2 Len=2: 129,11 |

If you use `BINARY_DOUBLE` instead of `NUMBER` (or `FLOAT`) then:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (predicted_arima BINARY_DOUBLE);
INSERT INTO table_name (predicted_arima) VALUES ( TO_BINARY_DOUBLE('9.1503E-140') );
SELECT predicted_arima FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | PREDICTED_ARIMA |
> | --- |
> | 9.1503000000000003E-140 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0bb21a738be9f99e846f00a44b8a54fc)*

Comment: thanks you were right. changing the Datatype in Oracle did work. One question- is there no way i handle this in python itself by reducing the value to <=127 scale?. The forecasting table is linked to many other codes/oracle tables and end result is presented in tableau. So there will too many changes to datatye right till tableau

Comment: @Biplab1985 You could multiply the value by 1e150 (or some similar value) and then store the adjusted value and then translate it back by dividing by 1e150 when you output it.

Comment: Could you help me?I am not sure about your above comment. I tried using ```pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.20f' % x)``` tried to set up the precision to 20 digits. it works well for array but not for above dataframe

Comment: The proper solution would be to convert to using `BINARY_DOUBLE` and to fix all the subsequent issues. If you want to use `NUMBER` data-type then, in python, you can multiple every `predicted_arima` value by 1e150 before you insert it into the table and then when you `SELECT` the value and read it into python you would need to divide all the values by 1e150 to return it to its original value. You have to do it in python as Oracle `NUMBER` data type does not support values that small. But, as I said, the best solution would be to use `BINARY_DOUBLE` and fix all the issues.